# Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=“xyz” --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1

Tags: linux, arch-linux, terminal, xfce, d-bus

I've been getting this error on multiple occasions. When I enter `sudo mousepad` I get the following output.

```
[privileged@arched ~]$ sudo mousepad

(mousepad:981): Mousepad-CRITICAL **: 14:12:48.549: Failed to initialize xfconf: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=91073612dabc1ec21befa5a96098e9f6 --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1
```

This error can also be seen when I try to meddle with the preferences of gedit. First I enter `sudo gedit` Which works fine and launches gedit. But when I try to change anything in the prefrence section such as the background colour or text size, It doesn't work and I the see the following error in the terminal

```
sudo gedit

(gedit:1104): dconf-WARNING **: 14:17:39.365: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=91073612dabc1ec21befa5a96098e9f6 --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1

(gedit:1104): dconf-WARNING **: 14:17:39.373: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=91073612dabc1ec21befa5a96098e9f6 --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1

** (gedit:1104): WARNING **: 14:17:39.528: Error loading plugin: libaspell.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(gedit:1104): dconf-WARNING **: 14:17:45.296: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=91073612dabc1ec21befa5a96098e9f6 --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1
```

Here's some information that I think might be useful

```
[privileged@arched ~]$ dbus-launch
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-PxRC1o8yHu,guid=fad87b8416da5e19055aef0d6098f385
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID=1140
[privileged@arched ~]$ cat /etc/machine-id 
91073612dabc1ec21befa5a96098e9f6
```

Is the problem with my terminal since it tried spawing it but failed? I am really lost here.