# How to change dconf settings in chrooted mode via terminal?

Tags: linux, chroot, dconf

I used `dconf write` and `gsetting set`, they worked on booted GUI desktop system. I tried to run them in a script in chrooted environment and got errors. Web search found QAs for similar errors: [Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=“xyz” --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/649035/error-spawning-command-line-dbus-launch-autolaunch-xyz-binary-syntax-cl), https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/n90sry/error_spawning_command_line_dbuslaunch/ but former does not have an answer and in later I see cause of error different from mine.

In man pages of `man 7 dconf`, `man dconf` I did not find how to select a specific database for edit. Is there a way?

I've tried to located dconf databases on working system, but even on system where `dconf write` worked, `$ echo $XDG_CONFIG_HOME` produces empty output, `/etc/dconf/profile/` does not exist, `$ echo $DCONF_PROFILE` produces empty output.

```
$ man 7 dconf
DCONF_PROFILE can specify a relative path to a file in
       /etc/dconf/profile/, or an absolute path (such as in a user's home
       directory).
A "user-db" line specifies a user database. These databases are found
       in $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/dconf/
```

Added 1 (as asked in the comment by @aviro):

```
# Commands invoked by the script include:
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/name "'Display rotate normal'"

gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings custom-list "['__dummy__', 'custom0', 'custom1', 'custom2', 'custom3']"

# output:
error: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=XXX --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1

(process:108725): dconf-WARNING **: 15:35:32.574: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=XXX --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1
```

The script is run via `sudo chroot fin_sq pathinsidenewroot/nameofscript`, where new root is mounted contents of Linux Mint Cinnamon edition distro iso:

```
mkdir iso to temp fin 
sudo mount $original_iso iso #  -o loop
sudo mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=iso,upperdir=to,workdir=temp overlay fin
mkdir iso_sq to_sq temp_sq fin_sq
sudo mount iso/casper/filesystem.squashfs iso_sq -t squashfs -o loop
sudo mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=iso_sq,upperdir=to_sq,workdir=temp_sq overlay fin_sq
```

Added 2:
Noted that whereas in "ordinary" environment both `dconf read /org/cinnamon/desktop/interface/text-scaling-factor` and `gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor` showed the same (1.0), in chrooted on that PC at about same time `gsettings get`  showed 1.0, but `dconf read` output was empty. When I've changed `text-scaling-factor` key (in ordinary), output of `gsettings get` in chrooted has not changed (output of `dconf read` in ordinary changed to new key value).

Comment: Can you please provide more details like what does your script looks like, how exactly do you run it, what are the errors you're seeing? It's really difficult to help with so little information. From the amount of details you've provided it could be anything in the world, starting from a syntax error in your script and ending with an alien induced computer virus.

Comment: @aviro, added, now the errors are easily reproducible (I hope).

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need to run this inside chroot environment? Is it supposed to be a sort of container? And also, what's your base OS? Is it the same like the chroot environmenr, Linux Mint Cinnamon?

Comment: @aviro, why do you think this matters? have you tried to reproduce? It is just mounts and gsettings. Myself doing it on same LM C, you guessed correctly.

Comment: It matters because if I'm going to try to reproduce it and to look for an answer or a solution for you, I'd would like to know it for a valid use case. Or if you're asking just for curiosity that's fine as well, but I have the right to ask, and it's customary to answer those questions. Often times people here ask questions they think will help them achieve something, while they were going in the wrong direction in the first place and there was another way for them to achieve what they wanted.

Comment: BTW, in case you didn't know, no one works here. Everyone have jobs, so no one is obliged to answer any question. So if someone shows signs he's interested in helping you, it's considered a courtesy to reply. I have some idea on why it doesn't work, but before I check this and try to make the effort to think about a solution, I would like to know your goal here because I might think of a better way for you to achieve what you want instead of this chroot method.

Comment: @aviro, AFAIK some do work here (mods). I saw questions from you but have not seen hints you can help, hence I was reluctant to add details second time. What I do not understand and see from you also is when a person puts effort to writing a long answer w/out upvoting the question. It puzzles me: if a question is not useful and/or shows no effort to be solved by the author, why go to such lengths to help?

Comment: I didn't upvote the question because yes, it didn't seem useful. But anyway, I use questions here not as a way to help people, but to learn thing. I use those questions as an opportunity to develop me knowledge and skills. In this case, I was curious to understand how `dconf` and `gsettings` work behind the scenes, and voila - "level up". So I didn't do it just for a slightly rude person I didn't know, I did it for myself.

Comment: The mods that work here are mostly enforcers, I don't think any of them are are trying to answer questions (at least not as part of their job). But my questions were valid. Your purpose was to create a modified live CD, and just solve the dconf-in-chroot issue, which was just a way to get to the target. You could have, for instance, run chroot in `singularity` container which would have probably worked eaiser, but wouldn't have helped you acheiving anything.

Comment: Your question could have been "how can I customuze my live CD", not assuming that chroot and dconf are the only way to achieve that, and get more relevant and helpful answers, instead of an answer that explains why what you're trying to do doesn't work and doesn't help you achieve you goal. It happens here **a lot**: People ask thing about a specific implementation they think will get them to the desired result, but when they explain what they're **really** trying to do, they get relevant answers for their specific need, and understand their initial way was a dead end to begin with.

Comment: @aviro. If you've learnt a thing, IMO question was useful to you. And to me learn that part of the software could be good even if the current problem could be solved another way. So thanks again for the effort.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `dconf` changes the configuration settings for a **specific user** that has X11 display running. So your first problem is that you run it as root. And even if you would attempt to switch to your own user, inside the chrooted environment your user and the groups don't appear in `/etc/{passwd,group}` inside the chrooted environment so it's not familiar with your user at all so you won't even be able to switch user. And even if you were able to switch (after bind mounting the relevant files from the host), you don't have your home directory in the chrooted environment. And even if you bind mounted your homedir to your chrooted environment and you can `su` to your user, you probably don't have your X11 sockets inside the chrooted environment and you still don't have your `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` after the `su`.

You can check the answers for [As root, I can use su to make dconf changes for another user. How do I actually make them apply?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1302886) to see some examples on how to do find/set/use `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`.

So you can see it's complicated enough to do this as root, and even more complicated to do that inside chrooted environment. Not impossible, but difficult. You will need to bind mount all of the relevant files/folders to the chroot folder before you even begin. That's why I asked what your use case is, and that's why I asked if you're attempting to use it as a sort of container (because some container tools, such as `singularity`, already do some of the work for you, like creating the relevant `passwd`/`group`, mounting your home dir, etc).

Regarding the following comment:

> in chrooted on that PC at about same time `gsettings get` showed 1.0,
> but `dconf read` output was empty.

Both `gsettings` and `dconf` (which is actually the backend for `gsettings` look in `$HOME/.config/dconf/user` or `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/dconf/user` for the user's configuration. If the configuration is not found there, `gsettings` will look for the default settings in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/gschemas.compiled`.

From `man glib-compile-schemas`:

> ```
>    glib-compile-schemas compiles all the GSettings XML schema files in
>    DIRECTORY into a binary file with the name gschemas.compiled that can
>    be used by GSettings. The XML schema files must have the filename
>    extension .gschema.xml. For a detailed description of the XML file
>    format, see the GSettings documentation.
>
>    At runtime, GSettings looks for schemas in the glib-2.0/schemas
>    subdirectories of all directories specified in the XDG_DATA_DIRS
>    environment variable. The usual location to install schema files is
>    /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas.
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When asking the question IIRC I thought there is some way to edit dconf database directly or something similar. Maybe I'll try to read linked askubuntu QA for more. BTW, I'm editing liveUSB to make it boot to live session customized to my wishes. I don't know a way better than chroot to edit it. I've tried to boot with persistence but failed to find a way to merge changes back to iso file.